# Wt,C++ и SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, linux, boost, qtcreator, sqlite3

Пытался разобраться с WebToolkit и написать по примерам свое приложение .
Но после начала работы с базой начались проблемы и последняя и не решенная мной это утечка памяти после передачи модели представлению а представления таблице элементов.

```
manTable = new Wt::WTable();
database *wsedb = new database();
wsedb->dbInit();
...
manView = new Wt::WTableView();
manView->setModel(wsedb->manModel);
manTable->elementAt(1,0)->addWidget(manView);
```

Не могу понять как решить эту проблему,совсем. Вроде как типы объявлены правильно, все заголовки подключены, в примерах разработчиков работа идет так же.
Сорцы:
database.h:

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H
#include<Wt/Dbo/backend/Sqlite3>
#include<Wt/Dbo/Dbo>
#include <Wt/Dbo/Session>
#include <Wt/Dbo/QueryModel>
#include <Wt/WApplication>
#include "manuals.h"//map clases
namespace dbo = Wt::Dbo;

class database
{
public:
    database();
    dbo::Session SessionW;
    dbo::QueryModel<dbo::ptr<manuals>> *manModel;
    void dbInit();
    void dbTrans();
    void addMan();
};

#endif // DATABASE_H
```

database.cpp:

```
#include "database.h"
using namespace Wt;

database::database()
{
}


void database::dbInit()
{
    dbo::backend::Sqlite3 wseDB=WApplication::instance()->appRoot() + "wse.db";
    SessionW.setConnection(wseDB);
    wseDB.setProperty("show-queries", "true");
    SessionW.mapClass<manuals>("manuals");
    manModel=new dbo::QueryModel<dbo::ptr<manuals>>();
    dbo::Transaction trans(SessionW);
    try{
        SessionW.createTables();
        Wt::log("info") << "Database created";

    } catch (...) {
        Wt::log("info") << "Using existing database";
    }
    trans.commit();
    manModel->setQuery(SessionW.find<manuals>());
    manModel->addAllFieldsAsColumns();
    dbo::Transaction trans1(SessionW);
    Wt::Dbo::collection<Wt::Dbo::ptr<manuals> > a=SessionW.find<manuals>().orderBy("date desc");
    trans1.commit();

}
```

Comment: Вы забыли удаление `manModel` в деструкторе `database`. Да и зачем `manModel` в куче создавать, а не на стеке?

Comment: Пытаюсь заставить работать пока,а потом уже рефакторить.
Только сейчас обратил внимание что деструктора вовсе нет в классе.

Comment: Сложно вам помочь, утечки на расстоянии не лечатся! Пробуйте кусками отключать код и проверятьть утечки, постепенно сужая область поиска.

Comment: Не нужно отключать куски кода. Попробуйте в отладчике найти место, на котором происходит аварийное завершение. С большой долей вероятности, это места обращения к указателям на объекты классов, которые вы выделили с помощью оператора `new`. Ставите там брейкпоинты, идёте, смотрите. Находите, обращение к какому указателю вызывает ошибку. Потом выясняете, где вы меняете этот указатель. Ну и Cerbo правильно отметил, что логичнее создать объект на стеке. Или же использовать умные указатели.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для отлова утечек памяти под линуксом есть замечательный инструмент - Valgrind. Ближайшая IDE с поддержкой Valgrind - Qt Creator.

Он ищет как утечки памяти, так и "наезды" указателей.